# Hover not working on Chrome and Dynamic Back Button

Tags: html, google-chrome, dynamic, hover

Site: http://heidenfreelance.com/FullSite/shop.html

When I view in Chrome, dropdown already displays. On Firefox, Hover works correctly.

Also, text back button does not work like the  button. I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: I've just tried your link in Chrome 12.0742.100 and Firefox 4.0.1 and they're working exactly the same (ul's displaying when the mouse moves over the images). Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Also using 12.0.742.100. It is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take note from this example: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/
It's a simple way to do what you're trying to do, which works consistently.

In my opinion,back buttons aren't worth thinking about. Browsers already have a back button.
Error pages, 404 etc, sometimes benefit from it, but really, a consistent navigation is what a site needs.